# highcharts: individual serie shift

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a highchart line chart, is it possible that, given two arrays A and B, to have B displayed after A?

eg: `A = [11,22,13,4,7], B=[6,11,45,7]`

to have `A[0]` at x=0, `A[1]` at x=1 ... `B[0]` at x=5, `B[1]` at x=6 ...?

If not, how can I have two styles (solid line and dashed) for the same set of data? essentially I want to build a chart of actual data and predictions and I want the predictions to appear in dashed lines

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two series of data - your A and B.
Set the A line color the way you want it and then set the B line color in its fashion. Use `dashStyle` to set the dashes. See [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data):

```
series: [{
        name: 'A',
        color: '#0066FF',
        data: [...]
    },{
        name: 'B',
        color: '#FF0000',
        dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
        data: [...]
    }]
```

As to how to set up the points to start on the 5th xAxis location. Well, many ways to skin a cat here. But what I did was to pass in null values for the first 4 data points in B.
Look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zW6GN/).

Comment: but i need to position B after A. How do i do that?